# pgAdmin 4 can't restore

Tags: pgadmin

I'm attempting to populate a database with a .sql file.  I'm on Windows 10 running pgAdmin 4.2. I have the binary paths set to "C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v1\runtime" which is where pg_dump.exe and pg_restore.exe are located.  I start a restore by browsing to either the sql file or the tar file. The format I select is "Custom or tar" I have no idea if I should be entering anything into the Number of jobs field. From Role name I select the user I created when I created the database (on AWS). I see a message thet the restore job was created, and then nothing happens.

I'm unsure if maybe something might be wrong with my install, but pgAdmin seems to be very slow to respond to mouse clicks and to do anything.  I have a confessedly older computer, but it has an i7 and 12gb RAM.  Other applications (like Workbench) do not run this slow.

Thanks in advance for your thoughts.

Comment: It is very slow for me too. I had restored via commad line and also installed pgAdmin 3.

Comment: Thanks @Alex ...  pgAdmin 3 worked like a charm.